# Are there memory limitations for Derby database running in embedded driver?

Tags: java, derby

How to get the memory used by derby database in eclipse IDE using java code.Is there any memmory limitation in derby embedded database.what is the maximum memmory can be used for derby in eclipse IDE.In my application I want to back up database and clear table datas while exceding the certain limits of memory.How to achieve this using java.To do this i want to know how to get the current memory usage and limit of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby imposes relatively few limitations on the number and size of databases and
database objects.

[image]

[Reference](http://dba.fyicenter.com/guide/Derby-Developer-Guide/25_Size_limits_for_Derby_database_objects.html)